# Matplotlib graph with typical linestyle not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want a very simple plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for t in np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100):
    plt.plot(np.cos(t), np.sin(t), color='blue', linestyle='-', linewidth=7)
plt.show()
```

But nothing is appearing. I just get an empty plot. Where is my error?

Comment: Matplotlib can plot arrays. There's no need to loop here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just plot the whole arrays:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100):
plt.plot(np.cos(t), np.sin(t), color='blue', linestyle='-',linewidth=7)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Each call to plt.plot within the for loop is plotting a separate 'line' that consists on only a single point.

if you want the code to work you should plot points instead of lines.

```
for t in np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100): plt.plot(np.cos(t), np.sin(t), 'k.')
```